# Scroll bar for TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I trying to place the scroll bar (both Vertical and Horizontal) for the table layout.

Here is my xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/prize_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

This is how I add the table row:

```
// header
row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setTextSize(18);
tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
tv.setText(R.string.prize_no);
row.addView(tv);

tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setTextSize(18);
tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
tv.setText(R.string.prize_name);
row.addView(tv);

layout.addView(row);

for (Prize prize : prizes) {
    row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setTextSize(18);
    tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
    tv.setText(prize.getPrizeID());
    row.addView(tv);

    tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setTextSize(18);
    tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
    tv.setText(prize.getPrizeName());
    row.addView(tv);

    layout.addView(row);
}
```

But I have some problem with these code

1. The vertical scroll bar cannot match with my content, let say I have 10 rows, but the scroll bar will be 10 times longer
2. The horizontal scroll bar is missing

Could anyone point out what problem in my code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several test, I found out that the problem was the

```
android:shrinkColumns="*"
```

After remove that, both problem was fixed
Hope this can help other people with same problem.